Asynchronous issues with useState in React Hooks
When I run the following code, a strange issue occurs :
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    {console.log("useEffect start")}                     // Step 1 after useEffect start
    const getApiData = async () => {
      console.log("async function start")                // Step 2
      const apiData = await fetch("https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random").then(res=>res.json());
      console.log("get API data")                        // Step 3
      setData(data.concat(apiData));
      console.log("after setData",data)}                 // Step 6
    getApiData();
  },[])
  console.log("outside useEffect",data);                 // Step 4

  return (<>
     <li>{data.map(i => <li>{i.value}</li>)}</li>
     {console.log("inside return")}                      // Step 5
  </>)}

export default App

Here are the sequence results from the console:
outside useEffect []
inside return
useEffect start
async function start
get API data
outside useEffect [{…}]  // Since useState(setData) is asynchronous, 
                         // why this step can get the return data value before setData is completed？
inside return
after setData []

What I don't understand is, if useState(setData) is asynchronous, why can I get the return value of data in Step 4? Since I can get the return value of data in Step 4, it means that useState(setData) has already completed before Step 4. If so, why does Step 6 come after Step 4? If useState(setData) has already been completed, then according to the sequence of the code lines, the next execution should be console.log("after setData", data) .  Do I miss something here?
I'm using React v18, but I'm also still using ReactDOM.render to bootstrap the app.
Stack Snippet:


<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<script type="text/babel" data-presets="es2017,react,stage-3">
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    {console.log("useEffect start")}                     // Step 1 after useEffect start
    const getApiData = async () => {
      console.log("async function start")                // Step 2
      const apiData = await fetch("https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random").then(res=>res.json());
      console.log("get API data")                        // Step 3
      setData(data.concat(apiData));
      console.log("after setData",data)}                 // Step 6
    getApiData();
  },[])
  console.log("outside useEffect",data);                 // Step 4

  return (<>
     <li>{data.map(i => <li>{i.value}</li>)}</li>
     {console.log("inside return")}                      {/* Step 5*/}
  </>)}

const root = ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
</script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/regenerator-runtime@0.13.2/runtime.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.10.3/babel.min.js"></script>





I will try to address directly the part which is most confusing.
Why do we get the below output?
get API data
outside useEffect [{…}]  

Isn't setState asynchronous?
setState batches state updates and delays rendering in most cases i.e., when the updates are from event handlers, but not from promises.
Here is the github isuse:
This is one of the useful comments:

This is entirely standard and intentional behavior. Currently, React only batches state updates that happen within its own event handlers. Logic in a promise callback is outside that event handler tick and thus outside the batching wrapper, so it's processed synchronously

To put it more clearly, get this example:
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

const onClick = async () => {
  setCounter(0);
  setCounter(1);

  const data = await fetchSomeData();

  setCounter(2);
  setCounter(3);
};

In React 17 and before,
setCounter(2);
setCounter(3);

will cause synchronous renders. Once setCounter sets the state to 2, it will cause a render. After that it will return and setState to 3, and cause another render.
Why setCounter(2), causes a render synchronously is because:

The call to setCounter(2) is happening after an await. The original
synchronous call stack is empty, and the second half of the function
is running much later in a separate event loop call stack. Because of
that, React will execute an entire render pass synchronously as the
last step inside the setCounter(2) call, finish the pass, and return
from setCounter(2).

I have picked up the explanation from this great blog
Most of the above I have mentioned applies to React 17. The above behaviour is different in React 18 (and above). React 18 is even more optimized for fewer renders :D. Hence TJ sees a different output.
React 18 sandbox
Output:

React 17 sandbox
Output:

The reason you still see this behaviour even after using React 18 is because ReactDOM.render does not support the features of React 18. To truly enable React 18, you will have to mount your React app like the below:
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App.tsx';

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(<App />);

ReactDOM.createRoot is a new method added in React 18.

Oh wow. I updated the Stack Snippet in the question to use React v17 and sure enough, it shows what the OP mentioned. Nice catch!!

But I check my react version is 18.2.0 in package.json. The bug still exists.

Make sure you are using ReactDOM.createRoot with React 18. If you use the older method ReactDom.render, React will auto assume you want to use React 17. New React 18 features won't work without createRoot method. Check the sandboxes I have added. docs -> https://react.dev/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18#react-dom-client

@T.J.Crowder yes, thanks. React changes too fast

@Tushar Shahi  Thank you, you are right. I was using ReactDom.render, here is the problem !

This is a good question @Mark and likely to be useful to others (certainly been useful to me). Thanks for the constructiveness!

@TusharShahi - And now I've updated the snippet in the question to use React v18 but with ReactDOM.render, and it does (of course) exactly what you (and Mark) said. Wild.

Thanks @T.J.Crowder. Someone with your credentials has found my answer useful. That will be the highlight of my week :D

@TusharShahi - LOL V. kind.

This is because React will run twice with useEffect in development mode.
Try see result after run build.
Or remove <React.StrictMode> component to disable the default behaviour.
Result:


Why -1, I already test, see the result picture. @Mark

I did not press -1 .  Your result sequence meets my expectations. But I still don't understand why, even if React runs twice with useEffect in development mode, step 6 does not appear before step 4?  It's strange,  right?

There's no indication from what's shown in the question that StrictMode is being used. If it were, there'd be a lot more logging. Separately, if StrictMode were the full answer, this would be an obvious duplicate of this and many others. @Mark - Are you using StrictMode? If so, did you leave out some of the logging?

I confirm that I don't use any StrictMode

Or you use Next.js? In next.js, even without StrictMode, it's default run useEffect twice, so if you use Next.js, add reactStrictMode: false to your next.config.js, like this:
const nextConfig = {
reactStrictMode: false
}
module.exports = nextConfig

Yeah, I check the No.1 answer and comments, TJ was right! thanks.

setData update all List   And then he did it again so you can again  see outside useEffect [{…}]
